# How to correctly edit /etc/cron.d/* files?

Tags: linux, cron

When I used

- `crontab -l` and
- `crontab -e`

I re-scheduled my cron timings, but found they were still firing at the previous interval.

I then discovered cron-format files under `/etc/cron.d/` which contain the previous scheduling, and I now assume it is these files which `cron` is obeying.

So I want to edit these, and remove the redundant "masking" lines from the main crontab, but the usage for `crontab` is:

```
usage:  crontab [-u user] file
        crontab [-u user] { -e | -l | -r }
```

So using `-l` or `-e` seems mutually exclusive with specifying the file.

What is the correct way to edit files `/etc/cron.d/*` ?

Comment: You're doing it wrong... but can you specify which OS version and distribution this is?

Comment: It's an outdated version of Ubuntu

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just use the editor of your choice to modify the cron.d files.

There's no need to use the `crontab` command.

Comment: Do you then need to tell the system something has changed? Anything which needs to be restarted?

Comment: nope. You don't.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the crontab command is only required to edit the user crontab.

Comment: Is there a reason why @ewwhite? That would help my understanding